# How can I convert fingerprint jpg to WSQ use JMRTD WSQEncoder.encode

Tags: java, image, fingerprint

I'm using JMRTD library (https://github.com/E3V3A/JMRTD/tree/master/wsq_imageio) to encode jpg to WSQ. I set Bitmap by manually instead of decode from WSQ file.

```
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(fileInput.getInputStream());
        WritableRaster raster = bufferedImage.getRaster();
        DataBufferByte data = (DataBufferByte) raster.getDataBuffer();
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(data.getData(), width, height, ppi, depth, lossyflag);

        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("c.wsq");
        String commentText = "";
        WSQEncoder.encode(outputStream, bitmap, bitrate, commentText);
```

Here is my original picture jpg:

[image]

And below is my result WSQ file:

[image]

How can I fix it. Many thanks!

Comment: Great question, you can get many upvotes if you share if you were able to solve it.

Comment: @DanOrtega, you can see my solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this problem, here is my code for convert jpg, png to wsq format:

```
// 1. Read files to BufferedImage for get width, height. Convert Bit depth to 8-gray
BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(fileInput.getInputStream());

// 2. Convert Bit depth to 8-gray (This is what i had to do to solve this problem)
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(bufferedImage.getWidth(), bufferedImage.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
Graphics g = img.getGraphics();
g.drawImage(bufferedImage, 0, 0, null);
g.dispose();

// 3. Convert file format to byte[] and convert to type Bitmap
WritableRaster raster = img.getRaster();
DataBufferByte data = (DataBufferByte) raster.getDataBuffer();
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(data.getData(), bufferedImage.getWidth(), bufferedImage.getHeight(), 500, 8, 1);

// 4. Create file wsq
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("c.wsq");
double bitrate = 0.75f;
String commentText = "";

// 5. Write the input file to the generated wsq file
WSQEncoder.encode(outputStream, bitmap, bitrate, commentText);
outputStream.close();
```

Hope help you @ Dan Ortega

Comment: I am just curious about which version of jmrtd or any other library you are using that has this code because none of the versions seem to work, especially the  WSQEncoder.encode ..which versions of this library/libraries should I use?